# Problem about installing mysql in my raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, mysql

Today when I tried to install mysql in my raspberry pi 2, problems happen as shown below: [image]

I use the command `apt-get install mysql-server python-mysqldb` to install mysql. Does any one know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

The issue is with mysql-common. Once you have run these commands, installation should be smooth.

Comment: And if you need to take screenshots, use Scrot

Answer (score 0):

I usually try finding answers from Ubuntu, if not Debian, otherwise general Linux. May or may not help.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/697805/package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet

Comment: Please do consider including relevant parts in of the link in the answer itself to prevent link rot.

Comment: **Provide context for links** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. So, while link only answers are indeed undesired and a potential reason for deletion I think we'll give you the chance to improve the answer. Please feel free to edit.